# Can I download a server world and build on it locally?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have an 'online' Minecraft server that I have been building on for the past couple of months. There are some big edits that I want to make on the map, but the server only has 512mb of RAM so it crashes.

My question is, **is it possible to download the world from the server so that I can load it up on my computer locally and run it in single player to make large edits**? I would later hope to re-upload the map onto the server after I finish making changes.

Answer (score 9):

If you own the server, and have access to its files, there is a simple solution.

First of all, navigate to your server files. It should look like this:

[image: Server root folder]

*Thanks to [John H](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/100265/104515) for the picture.*

Next, copy the folder named 'world'.

Then press <kbd>Windows/Super</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the run program. Type `%appdata%` and press enter.

Navigate to the saves folder. Click on '.minecraft' then  'saves'.

Finally, paste the world folder into 'saves'. Open up minecraft, and you should see it!

Repeat this process in reverse to save the world back to the server.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a mod for this:
[World Downloader Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1285484-world-downloader-mod)

Comment: This could be a useful answer if you do not have access to the files, but as it stands is not much more than a link. I've been using this mod recently in an effort to 'rescue' a bunch of my large-scale structures from a server that isn't as well taken care of as it once was. I'll try to write up a more detailed explanation of this method tonight.